# can I shift an email address from one iCloud account to another

Tags: icloud

I setup iMessages/facetime to receive emails on a certain email address. I want to use that email address instead on a totally separate icloud account. How can I do this?

Comment: Does any of [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph2622) help you out? If not, can you just login to itunes or appstore or whatever and change the email address associated with the account?

Comment: no unfortunately. I associated some additional emails with an icloud account - and I want to "free them up" so they can be used elsewhere.

Comment: You might want to flag your own question and request a migration to http://apple.stackexchange.com/ if you need additional help with this. Or maybe even http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ .